# Is there a way to write an index.d.ts declaration file type that defines a type of a standard js object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Lets say I have a variable

```
const obj = {
    a: {
        'b': 1,
    },
    c: {
        'd': 2,
        'e': 'hello',
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a type that is defined as `Record<'a' | 'b', typeof a object (i.e Record<'b', number>) | type of b object (i.e. Record<'d' | 'e', number | string>) >` Is there an easy way to do this in typescript so that this is automatically inferred?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare this object in TypeScript, it will infer the following type:

```
type TypeofObj = {
  a: {
    b: number;
  };
  c: {
    d: number;
    e: string;
  };
};
```

If you'd like a more string type like this:

```
type TypeofObj = {
  a: {
    b: 1;
  };
  c: {
    d: 2;
    e: "hello";
  };
};
```

The define the object as `const` like so:

```
const obj = {
    a: {
        'b': 1,
    },
    c: {
        'd': 2,
        'e': 'hello',
    }
} as const;
```

Comment: Ok so currently, the object is defined in a js file like `module.exports = {myobject}`. What should I write in the package's index.d.ts file to export the type of this object? The object is default exported

Comment: you can define the type like I did, and then just `export default TypeofObj`